# Wrinkles at the bottom of a pan of hot water

Tags: thermodynamics, water

I notice that when I boil water, as it heats up, slender wrinkles appear at the bottom of the pan and twist like snakes around the surface. Eventually they disappear as bubbles of water vapor appear and take their place.

What are these wrinkles?

Comment: Probably what you are witnessing is thermal plumes.

Comment: From the water H20